# Changing from Your Account to Customer Name

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Is there any hook which can change "YOUR ACCOUNT" text to User Name or the User ID?

[image: Image below]

Comment: Where do you see "Your account"? I think it depends on the theme.

Comment: Have you tried using a custom walker class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question! The best way to do that is the filter hook "the_title" which is used to display page title. You need to check if the user is login and if it's your page before change to user name.

Here is a proposition of code to put in your functions.php:

```
function wc_filter_page_title($title, $id = null) {
  if( is_user_logged_in() && strtolower($title) == 'your account' ){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    return $current_user->display_name;
  } else {
    return $title;
  }
}
add_filter('the_title', 'wc_filter_page_title', 10, 2 );
```

This code needs some changes if you have in a multilanguage website, if the page title is different or if you only wants to make this change in the menu.

Comment: Since the second parameter is the post/page ID I think you'd be better served by checking if you are on the account page as your condition. Ex: `if( is_user_logged_in() && $id == wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) )`

Comment: Yes, good idea! But it can be a little bit more tricky. For example, in a menu it's not giving the page id but the nav menu item ID. But it can be a very good solution to target the menu, like the screenshot.

Comment: Good point. I didn't see the screenshot and didn't realize it was about the menu. I've edited the question so the image shows up.